# How do I exclude a folder from a URL using Regex?

Tags: regex

I need to use Regex to check for URLs that contain 'folder', in the following URL:

subdomain.domain.co.uk/section/folder/page

I'm using:

```
subdomain.domain.co.uk\/.*\/(?!folder\/).*
```

but it's still finding 'folder'. Any ideas?

Comment: Programming language? Regex flavor ?  Show us how you compare ...

Comment: Your title doesn't really fit to the content. Do you want the regex to match subdomain.domain.co.uk/section/folder/page or not?

Comment: How about some sample URLs that match and some that don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^subdomain.domain.co.uk\/((?!folder).)*$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need slashes around "folder", otherwise you'll also exclude "/anotherfolder/" and "/folder.jpg" etc.

Put the negative look ahead *before* the ".*" and add ".*" *before* "folder":

```
subdomain.domain.co.uk\/(?!.*\/folder\/).*
```

This won't match a URL with "/folder/" anywhere in it.